# React App docker image not picking up env variables from ubuntu host

Tags: reactjs, docker, ubuntu, amazon-s3, docker-compose

We have docker instance deployed for FE (frontend) and BE (backend), and environment variables are set using Docker-Compose file. We have deployed Docker Swarm architecture. Environment variables working fine when BE is fetching database credentials to connect to DB. But not working on the FE, which is a Create React App. And in React app, I'm using it like process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME.

The job I'm trying to achieve is to save the images on S3 bucket, and expect the React app to fetch the S3 credentials from environment variables. But it keeps showing this error that "n is undefined". While n is not a variable or object defined in the image sending function.

An object is sent along with the images' data where the environment variables are used.
This is the object:

```
{
  bucketName: process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME,
  dirName: subject,
  region: process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME,
  accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME,
}
```

If I add the S3 credentials manually, the images get saved successfully, but not when the environment variables are used.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]; how do those variables get set?  I'd be surprised to see a front-end application (and correspondingly an end user's browser) to have valid AWS credentials; the S3 handling would more likely happen in the back-end application, and ideally it would get AWS credentials implicitly through the EC2 metadata service or the EKS OpenID Connect interface.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the suggestion. We've taken step to move S3 credentials from frontend to the backend for the efficient handling and for the security purpose as well.